# What is the probability that a random graph contains an $m$ clique.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a simple random graph $G$ with $n$ vertices where every edge is present with probability $p$ independently of the others, what is the probability that $G$ contains a clique of size $m$?

The probability that a particular set of $m$ vertices is a clique is $p^{m \choose 2}$ and there are ${n \choose m}$ such sets, but the probability clearly isn't ${n \choose m}p^{m \choose 2}$...so what do I do?

Comment: Does a clique of size greater than $m$ count?

Comment: If $G$ has a clique of size greater than $m$, than it also has a clique of size $m$, so yes.

Comment: Is it a simple graph or can it contain parallel edges?

Comment: It is simple. I'll add it to the question, thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383235/probability-of-a-graph-having-at-least-1-k-clique and some of the references there for asymptotic results/ bounds. I would not hold out hope for an exact answer.

Comment: The probability of not having an edge is $1-p$, There are $\binom{n}{2}-\binom{m}{2}$ edges between the two complete graphs.